# Create a Box Using Gazebo API

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How do I use Gazebo API to create a model?
I want to implement a world plugin that creates a box with its size defined by a custom message, but I cant find any example of how to create a model using Gazebo API

Thanks for the help

Eduardo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6908/create-a-box-using-gazebo-api/) by [Eduardo Albuquerque](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/948/eduardo-albuquerque/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 89 on 2014-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is code in [gazebo/gui/BoxMaker](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/2591f9537eaeaf1ae24a48d9e86f961a9c774980/gazebo/gui/BoxMaker.cc?at=default) that you can use.

The BoxMaker class creates an SDF for a box, and sends the SDF string in a factory message on the `~/factory` topic. You should also look at BoxMaker's parent class [EntityMaker](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/2591f9537eaeaf1ae24a48d9e86f961a9c774980/gazebo/gui/EntityMaker.cc?at=default).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eduardo Albuquerque](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/948/eduardo-albuquerque/) on 2014-08-27**:
Thanks for your advice! That will be useful! That's a good starting point.
Actually, I'm trying to implement a Remote Client for creating/modifying models (e.g. a robotic arm) dynamically. Can I use the API for add/modifying links and joints in a model that I created before. If I do, is there any sample code?
If I can't, I'm thinking about modifying the model SDF description and reload it in the world every time the user modifies the model.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-08-28**:
Editing an existing model as you have described is not recommended. Try removing the current model, and add a new model.